# How to pass object from UIViewController to Custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift

This AssetRFPViewController class call a custom view(AssetBasicInfo) in viewDidLoad, if a pass "Hello" its ok but when i pass object to custom view(AssetBasicInfo) its not taken, How can i design a custom view class so its catch object

```
class AssetRFPViewController: UIViewController
{
 var asset:Asset = Asset()
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        let customView = AssetBasicInfo(frame: self.topHeaderView.bounds)
        customView.assetNameValLbl.text = "Hello" // ok
        customView.assetObj = self.asset      // not ok, passing object
        self.topHeaderView.addSubview(customView)
       }
}
```

Now my custom class look like this,

```
class AssetBasicInfo: UIView {
                @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
             var assetObj:Asset = Asset() // i want value in this object "assetObj"
            @IBOutlet var assetNameValLbl: UILabel!

            override init(frame: CGRect) {
                    super.init(frame: frame)
                    print(frame.size.width)
                    print(frame.size.height)

                    commonInit()
                }
 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder : aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
        private func commonInit(){

                Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderViewXIB", owner: self, options: nil)
                self.addSubview(containerView)
                self.containerView.frame = self.frame
                containerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]

                self.assetNameValLbl.text = assetObj.name // not setting value
                print("screenName" , screenName)
            }
    }
```

Comment: Write custom delegate methods to send messages.

Comment: What do you mean it is not taken?

Comment: UIView class(AssetBasicInfo: UIView) not getting the object which passed from  UIViewController class(AssetRFPViewController). Any one tell me how to pass the object from View Controller class to View class